# Как пересчитать количество символов каждой из строк?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день, подскжите как пересчитать количество симвоволов в каждой строке отдельно.

```js
var str = $('.str')

function leng() {
    if(str.text().length > 10) {
        console.log(str.text().length)
    }
};

leng();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='str'>123456789011</div>
<div class='str'>123456789011</div>
<div class='str'>123456789011</div>
<div class='str'>123456789011</div>
```

На данный момент функция выбирает все символы из всех строк, просто мне нужно менять шрифт если одна из строк большая шрифт становиться меньше.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var str = $('.str'); 
// Тут у вас коллекция jQuery - объектов
console.log(str.length)

function leng() {
    // Соотвественно текст собирается по всей коллекции -
    console.log(str.text()); 
    // Нужно перебрать по одному:
    str.each((index, elem) => {
        console.log($(elem).text().length);
        // Как-то так:
        // if($(elem).text().length > 11) $(elem).addClass('long');
    });
};

leng();



//PS: И jQuery для этого не нужен.
var str = document.getElementsByClassName('str');
[...str].forEach(el => {
  if(el.innerText.length > 11) el.classList.add('long');
});
```

```css
.long{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='str'>1234567890</div>
<div class='str'>12345678901</div>
<div class='str'>123456789012</div>
<div class='str'>1234567890123</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо это понял, как теперь добавить условие? например если в строке больше чем 10 символов аттачить какой-нибуль класс?

Comment: @AntonEssential обновил ответ

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```js
var str = $('.str'),
    fs = 12;

function leng() {

    str.each(function() {
 
        if($(this).html().length > 10 ) {
        
            $(this).css("font-size",fs);
            
        }
    
    })
    
};

leng();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='str'>12345678901191234567890119</div>
<div class='str'>1234567890</div>
<div class='str'>1234567</div>
<div class='str'>1234</div>
```

Comment: Понятно, я вам  плюсану, так как уже выделил решение, однако спасибо большое.